# show view count on rss feed in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, rss, drupal-views

i have a drupal site and i want to add to the RSS feed a view count

what that i found that should do this is this code
but so far i get a null value

```
<?php print $node->links['statistics_counter']['title']; ?>
```

and i can't run any SQL query because i can't match the nodes for it.

i also tried to do:

```
print_r($node->links['statistics_counter']);
```

and also i get an empty array

any help is appreciated

Comment: <?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?> or [statistics counter] (http://diggit.drupalextras.com/node/43223/related_links)

Comment: i'm sorry but i still didn't had any time to test it out

Comment: Are you trying to modify the default RSS feed at `/rss.xml`? Where are you putting in the code that you have?

Comment: On the admin panel, on the page that I can manage the rss

Comment: Are you putting your php code into the `Feed description` box at `admin/config/services/rss-publishing`?  (this is in Drupal 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: `<?php print $node->links['statistics_counter']['title']; ?>`. Be sure that you print it in teaser mode, not in full view (`$page == 1`). 
If not, visit http://YOURSITE/admin/reports/settings and enable access log.
 
p.s. Also [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module provide more powerfull feed page with any data and filters.

Comment: what do you mean ($page == 1)?

Comment: Node have predefined variables, like $page and $teaser, each mean on what mode you view now node. rss use teaser.